# Proper way to use data returned by an asynchronous function (web scraping example)

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, closures

So I have this simple code to mine some videos url in order to apply another scraping function to it afterward. My problem is that I can't seem to return the url-filled array. I know that it's a problem of scope but I'm not that familiar with Javascript and my knowledge got me as far as I could.

Here is the code :

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var startUrl = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/mostviewed';

var getVideoIds = function(url) {

    var urls = [];

    request(url, function(err, resp, body){
        if (err)
            throw err;
        $ = cheerio.load(body);


        var videoUrls = [];
        $('.videoTitle a').each(function() {
            videoUrls.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });

   return urls;
}


var urlsToScrap = getVideoIds(startUrl);
console.log(urlsToScrap);
```

PS : the current code returns an empty array;

Comment: Let me check that out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues.  One is that you're returning `urls` but it's never set to anything.  You are pushing values onto `videoUrls` but you're returning the empty `urls` array.  The other is that `request` is an asynchronous function.  You will need to set a callback to set the video urls once it brings the scraped data back.

So:

```
var urls = [];

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('.videoTitle a').each(function() {
        urls.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    onVideosScraped();
});

function onVideosScraped() {
    console.log(urls);  
}
```

This should work, and is a rudimentary way to do it.  You can of course wrap any of this you want in functions to make it more reusable, but I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes it does, I was about to post almost the same answer !
Thank you !